# Where can I find a Windows app to view text type files like Photos views images?

Tags: windows, text

I'm looking for a Windows app to view text type files like "Photos" views images.

In Photos, I can "scan" the image files in a folder by clicking the arrows on right or left of the image or using the left/right keys on the keyboard.  I would like to have the same mechanism but be able to see the text content of files.  I don't really want an editor.

Prefer a free open-source program.

Thanks in advance.
RONC

Comment: I didn't see Mac anywhere in the title.  Is there an equivalent windows site?

Comment: i'm sorry, this is not a mac site.  please ignore my stupid commemt.

Comment: No problem.  I've been in the wrong place often.